# Apache Tika - Document to XHTML - Not getting the images

Tags: apache-tika

I am trying to convert a Word Document to an XHTML document. I am using version V 1.24. The code I am using is exactly as per the [landing page](https://tika.apache.org/1.8/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML)

Reproducing code for reference:

```
org.xml.sax.ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();

AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
File initialFile = new File("C:\\TikaHTML\\Doc3.docx");
InputStream targetStream = 
    new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(initialFile));    

parser.parse(targetStream, handler, metadata);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\TikaHTML\\Doc3.XHTML"));
writer.write(handler.toString());
writer.close();
targetStream.close();
```

When I try to open the XHTML file in the browser, I am getting an encoding related error. Thanks to below comment, this was resolved.
[image]

Also, why am I not getting the Images? The file has tags like below:

```
<p><img src="embedded:image6.png" alt="image6.png" /></p>
```

Comment: Try specifying UTF-8 encoding when you create your writer to write out?

Comment: Thank you @Gagravarr. Any idea why I am not getting the Images? Updated the description

Comment: You need to register an embedded handler to get the embedded resources, then convert the src to point to wherever your handler saves the files too